# Average rate of change - many variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been searching here and on google about average rate of change. The examples only use x axis. But my problem is how to use with many variables.

The temperature at a point (x, y) on a flat metal plate is given by the function T(x,y) = 9x² + 4y².

A ant is at the point (2,1) and walks to the x axis direction. That means in the line y = 1 to the level curve z = 80. Compute the average rate of change of temperature experienced by the ant.

How do I use with many variables and level curve?

Comment: Substitute $y=1$ Into $T$ and you get a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: I did this. The result of my teacher is 44,4. How can I get that?